# page load complete then my add class is gone

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  $(".main_menu ul li").click(function(){
    $(".main_menu ul li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

  $(".main_menu ul li").click(function(){
    $("#camera_wrap_3").addClass("camera_height");
    $(".promotion_area").remove();
  });

});
```

This is my jquery code and its working. but when I convert my template to wordpress, then its also working after loading page.. but when page load complete then my add class is gone.
What should I do in position?

Comment: Why do you have two functions for the same click event?

Comment: If I use one, then there is same problem

Answer (score 0):

Check your javascript console, does is say "$ is not defined" or similar?

Wordpress loads jQuery in "noconflict mode", modify your javascript to use the jQuery object (instead of $)

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't need 2 click events.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".main_menu ul li").click(function(){
    jQuery(".main_menu ul li.active").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    jQuery("#camera_wrap_3").addClass("camera_height");
    jQuery(".promotion_area").remove();
  });

});
```

Comment: there is no similar problem. when page loading then its show but when complete then class is out

Comment: this problem only wordpress